# Generate a password protected CSV file using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I want to protect a csv file with password using Azure Data Factory. The file is located in Datalake. I have full access to the datalake folders.

Is there any way that I can do this in ADF?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Arjun Rathinam

Comment: What is your purpose for wanting to password protect a CSV file? Are you wanting to encrypt it so that people who have access to download the file will not be able to read it without decryption? Or are you trying to restrict who can access it? Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 or Gen2?

Comment: This is just for security purpose. So that the next step would be decryption and then load the data into DWH tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't actually password protect a CSV file by itself, like mentioned here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/778720/How-I-can-make-csv-file-password-protected. It's just a text file like .txt files.

It would need to be wrapped in a file format that does support encryption and password protection, a couple options mentioned here: https://www.import2.com/csv/how-to-encrypt-a-csv-file.

> Option 1: Compress your CSV file to a zip folder, and them encrypt that folder.
>
> Option 2: Import the CSV file into a spreadsheet software (like Excel or Numbers) and then add your password encryption.

Comment: Hi Juunas,

Thanks for your inputs. I can go with both Option 1 and Option 2. 

Can I know how to password protect Option1 or Option2 using ADF?